# How to handle Veracode error for MVC's Model's property for a password field?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows-authentication, securestring, directoryentry

I have a model for login logic. It contains a property called Password:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = " ")]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
public string Password { get; set; }
```

When Veracode scans the model it produces the following error:

> CWE-316: Cleartext Storage of Sensitive Information in Memory

My view is generating the Password field as follows:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Password}
```

Then, along the line in the model, I'm using the following Windows Authentication logic to check if the user is a windows user:

```
DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties().DomainName, username, password, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
```

The above class' constructor requires password as a string.

What would be the best solution that could fix the Veracode problem and allows me to use the logic I already have?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was an easy one. I just have to change the declaration `Password` to `UserIdnt`.

Now `Veracode` doesn't recognize it as a security threat and let it go